# Issue - allowDefinition = MachineToApplication beyond application level

Tags: c#, web-config, iis-7.5

I created virtual directory and mapped to application in IIS 7.5 Windows 7.

Then am trying to build the application, am getting this error message.

"It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. "

What shall I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the offending section from the Web.config file in the virtual directory (whatever it is, the problem section can't be identified from the negate information in the question).

Alternatively, you haven't correctly created the virtual directory as an application in IIS.

Comment: This problem is very strange. If launch debug of my website in VS2010 I've this error but the develope server asp net working 1471 port ... I don't understand ...

Comment: Development server doesn't normally use virtual directories, so wouldn't experience the issue.

Comment: I've follow this tutorial ... in debug VS2010 I've error ...
http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/7_0/devguide/index.html?creating_a_virtual_directory.htm